# <option> Seleccionado por default

Tags: php, html, jquery

Lo que quiero es que por default seleccione todos
y en el campo aparezca 'Seleccionado todos'

```
<label>Producto:</label>
    <select name="product" id="product" >

        <?

        foreach($prodsArr as $sucId => $prods){
            echo '<option value="" id="'.$sucId.'"'; if($_POST['product']=='') echo ' selected'; echo '>Seleccionados todos</option>';
            foreach($prods as $code => $prod){
                echo '<option id="'.$sucId.'M'.$code.'" value="'.$code.'"'; 
                if($_POST['product']==$code and $restId==$sucId)
                 echo 'selected'; echo '>'.$prod.'</option>';



            }

        }

        ?>
        <label>Producto:</label>
        <select name="product02"   id="product02" >

        </select>
        </div>
        <?
            $col = $col + 2;
            $jsvars .= 'var product02 = $("#product02").val();
            ';
            if($fcount!==1) $params .= ',';
            $params .= 'product02';
            $fproduct2 = false;
        /*  $("#select").multipleSelect({
                    url:'data1.json'
            });*/


    }

     elseif($freporteDetalle_){ ?>
```

Al recargar la web si inicia diciendo seleccionados todos pero al segundo se quita y se queda en blanco, cual seria la solucion de favor.

Comment: estas mezclando php con jquery?, es mala práctica estimado , ademas no creo que funcione.

Comment: para que se seleccionen todos debera ser un select tipo multiple, caso contrario no funcionara

Comment: el select como lo tienes definido en tu html no es multiple para que sea multiple debes hacer algo como esto: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp